# Using Regex to delete strings in a string

Tags: regex

I have the following string:

```
m_VAR.A2345_DISCHRG_REASON_CODE 
m_VAR.A2611A_DISCHRG_REASON_CODE.TrimStart("0"c)
```

I need to find all of these and make it:

```
m_VAR.A2345
m_VAR.A2611A.TrimStart("0"c)
```

How can I do this using regular expression?

Yes, I used "DISCHRG_REASON_CODE" as an example. We will get codes:

```
m_VAR.A2345_XXX_XXXX_XXX 
m_VAR.A2611A_DISCHRG_REASON_CODE.TrimStart("0"c)
.A2111E_YUIU_UIOUUOIU
```

and I only want the string after the period (including the period) and before the first "_"

Comment: `_DISCHRG_REASON_CODE` is a regular expression you can use to replace `_DISCHRG_REASON_CODE` with nothing

Answer (score 0):

Just do a find for `_DISCHRG_REASON_CODE` and then replace that with empty string.  This assumes that this code only appears once in your data.  If it could appear multiple times, then you should update your question and show us sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Something like `:%s/\(\<\)\@<!_DISCHRG_REASON_CODE\>//g` if you use Vim.